# How can I use Maven to automate multiple builds?

Tags: java, maven

I have to manage multiple projects like A1..A5 and B1..B3. Each of the Bs depends on a specific set of the As. So I can start maven manually on every A then every B to create all jars. Starting Maven in one of the Bs will not even precompile the required As.

Is there any solution to do this just with Maven without additional tools like shell scripts or Ant?

And just to prevent answers like "move folder A into folder B": all folders are in one directory on the same level. That cannot be changed because different teams are working on this projects and each project has its own GIT repository.

Comment: No, I don't think so. You will need another tool.

Comment: You have to use tool like Jenkins to build upstream dependencies (all A's) first and then build downstream dependencies. You are trying to automate CI/CD with Maven, which is not the use-case of Maven.

Comment: If you can decouple all A's and B's then you can use them as modules. And have one parent pom. Building parent pom will build all children poms too.

Comment: Jenkins and TeamCity allow to configure build in such way that if any of dependencies are rebuilt then build for dependent project is started automatically

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. Do you want to build all in one command? Or any B with automatically recompiling all needed As, or B without recompiling As (using last successful build..)?

Comment: I have to produce a WAR file for every B which also includes some of the A-jars. E.g. B1 includes A1 and A2 while B2 includes A2 and A3.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to get it to work like this:

- create an "aggregator build": a POM project that lists the individual projects A1...A5 and B1...B3 as `<modules>` which is checked in to a separate git repository
- in that git repository, configure git submodules which point to the other repositories

When starting a build on the aggregator project, Maven will automatically figure out the correct build order based on the dependencies of the included projects.

For example, given the following dependencies:

```
B1 uses A1 and A2
B2 uses A2 and A3
B3 uses A3, A4 and A5
```

Maven might come up with a build order of A1, A2, B1, A3, B2, A4, A5, B3.

Using Maven command line options, an aggregator build can even be started as "rebuild A3 and everything that uses it" or "rebuild everything needed for B1, then B1 itself".

However, all this may require that the individual projects inherit from the aggregator POM, which may or may not be feasible in your situation depending on what your POMs look like.

The directory structure could look like this:
[image: example multi-module project structure]

Comment: That sounds promising. So I have a folder "aggregate" which only contains a pom.xml. How must this ony look like to build the targets from the other projects? Should be possible in my situation that all As and Bs inherit from this aggregator pom but they cannot inherit between them.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it would be as simple as invoking `mvn <goals and parameters go here>` in the `aggregator` directory. Maven would then figure out a build order and run the given goals for all projects which are modules of the aggregator build.

Comment: Hi Jens. Would it be possible for you to provide a small example? I'm having multiple microservice projects (lets call them A1 to An). All of them are using some (very few) common services. So I put these into project B1. B1 also contains the private key used for JWT authentication. But the key must be available in each Ax. Any ideas?

Comment: B1 (named e.g. "microservices") should have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` and the `<modules>` list I mentioned in my answer. It will not create a JAR file, so your JWT authentication private key must reside in a separate project C1 (named e.g. "common" or "shared"). Then, in the B1 pom, add a dependency to C1. As each Ax microservice inherits from the B1 pom, it also gets that dependency. Finally, you should add another project R1 (named e.g. "root"), also with `pom` packaging, which acts as an aggregator for its `modules` B1 and C1. R1 resides at the root of your project directory structure.

Comment: Note that hard-coding a private key in your project sources sounds like a bad idea, but that's a topic for another post.

Answer (score 0):

If the As and Bs really are different projects you'll need some other tool like Jenkins to mangage and orchestrate your builds. Especially you'll be doing independent releases of the As and Bs, so you'll want to keep the Maven builds independent.